# How can i print the progress bar on tqdm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tqdm

How can I get the progress bar at the output in this Python code? I tried some answers here, but nothing works well for me

I used "tqdm" library on Python 3.8.8, Windows 10 on CMD

Here is what I tried:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

LIST = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
total = len(LIST)
bar = tqdm(total, desc='Processing')
for u in LIST:
    bar.update(LIST.index(u))
```

Here is the output that I keep getting:

```
Processing: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]
Processing: 3it [00:00, 96.15it/s]
```

Any help please?

Comment: What output would you want to get?  Your loop takes essentially no time to execute, so there's no reason for the progress bar to update before the end of the loop.

Comment: I also wants it for complex scripts..

Comment: I just want it to be shown at least.

Comment: Have you tried it on more complex, larger data, etc. processes that actually takes time to run?

Comment: Clearly I did and above you can see the output I need a progress bar like this shape  33%|███▎ | 1/3

Answer (score 0):

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

LIST = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']

for u in tqdm(LIST):
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: This intentionally makes the processing slower, just so to display a progress bar. It is counter-productive.

Comment: @RJ Adriaansen Is there a way to print the progress bar in one line instead of printing each in a new line?  
0%|          | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
33%|███▎      | 1/3 [00:05<00:10,  5.00s/it]
67%|██████▋   | 2/3 [00:10<00:05,  5.00s/it]
100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:15<00:00,  5.00s/it]
100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:15<00:00,  5.00s/it]

Comment: @GinoMempin the for loop was empty anyway as `tqdm` automatically updates the progress bar. @user15125446, are you running on colab? I ran into that issue there. This should work: `for u in tqdm(LIST, position=0, leave=True):`